# Php Program to find Palindrome?

Tags: php

Three steps to find the palindrome?

1. use `strrev` on the given value
2. Then split using the `str_split`.
3. Then use `foreach` and `concate` the split value.

Example

```
$a = "madam";

$b =  strrev($a);

    $string_reverse = str_split($b);

    $palin = '';

    foreach($string_reverse as $value){

        $palin.= $value; 
    }

    print $palin;

    if($a == $palin){

        print "<br>Palindrome";

    } else {

        print "<br>Not Palindrome"; 

    }
```

**Output**

> madam
>   Palindrome

Comment: Yes reversing and comparing equality is one way. What is the question?

Comment: There's indeed no question in here, but you can shorten all this to : `function is_palindrome($a) { return $a === strrev($ab); }`

Comment: There is no question here, @sudhakar--please modify to actually ask a question

Answer (score 9):

try this:

```
<?php
function check_plaindrome($string) {
    //remove all spaces
    $string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);

    //remove special characters
    $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);

    //change case to lower
    $string = strtolower($string);

    //reverse the string
    $reverse = strrev($string);

    if ($string == $reverse) {
        echo "<p>It is Palindrome</p>";
    } 
    else {
        echo "</p>Not Palindrome</p>";
    }
}

$string = "A man, a plan, a canal, Panama";
check_plaindrome($string);


########Output#######
<p>It is Palindrome</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

To check a string whether it is palindrome or not without PHP function.

```
<?php 

    $str = 'level';
    $strLen = strlen($str)-1;
    $revStr = '';
    for($i=$strLen; $i>=0; $i--){
        $revStr.=$str[$i];
    }
    if($revStr == $str)
        echo 'Palindrome';
    else
        echo "Not Palindrome";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way who we can write like this to don't make it complicate:

```
$a = "1681";

$b =  strrev($a);

print $b;

if($a == $b){

    print "<br>Plaindrome";

} else {

    print "<br>Not Plaindrome"; 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function checkpala(string $input){

    for( $i=0; $i < strlen($input); $i++){   //for each char in the string
        if (substr($input,$i,1) != substr($input, strlen($input)-($i+1),1)){  //get the first char and the last char and compare them.  Then get the 2nd and the 2nd from the end and compare them.  repeate

            //if at any point there is no match, stop checking, return false
            //echo "$input is not a palindrome";
            return false;
         }
    }
    //if the loop completes and every character checked out, return true.
    //echo "$input is a palindrome";
    return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it reverses the string or value...

```
function fn_palindrome($palindrome) {
    $reversed = ''; 
    $original = $palindrome;
    $string = array(); $j = 0;
    $converted = (string) $palindrome;
    $palindrome = str_split($converted);
    $i = count($palindrome) - 1;
    while($i >= 0) {
        $string[$j] = $palindrome[$i];
        $j++; $i--;
    }
    $reversed = implode('', $string);
    if($reversed == $original) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkPalindrome($string) {
    return $string == strrev($string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$word = "level";  // declare a varibale
echo "String: " . $word . "<br>";
$reverse = strrev($word); // reverse the word
if ($word == $reverse) // compare if  the original word is same as the reverse of the same word
echo 'Output: This string is a palindrome';
else
echo 'Output: This is not a palindrome';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dummy String to be tested

```
$s = 'abcdefg';
```

Reverse the string order

```
$t = strrev($s);
```

Get the length of the string

```
$length = mb_strlen($s);
```

Variable to be used for concating string while traversing using for loop

```
$new = '';
```

Loop to traverse string

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $new = $s[$i].$new;    
}
```

Check string traversed using for loop is equal to string reversed using PHP function

```
if ($s == $new){
    echo "Yes palindrome";
} else {
    echo "No palindrome";
}
```

If output is yes then it is palindrome otherwise it is Not a palindrome string.

*** I have update the answer.

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are not very helpful and commonly frowned upon.

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some additional info regarding **how** your code solves the problem at hand. Doing so aids those with similar (but not identical) problems. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)

Comment: I used this code and it says 'abcdefg' is a palindrome, which it clearly is not.

Comment: @Brogan Sorry, There was  mistake on if clause. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
function checkPalindrome($string){
   $string = strtolower($string);
   $reverse = strrev($string);
       if($string == $reverse){
          return true;
       } else {
          return false;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
<?php
  $strng = 'SMS';
  $rvsstr = '';
  $i = 0;
  while (!empty($strng[$i])) {
    $rvsstr = $strng[$i].$rvsstr;
    $i++;
  }
  // echo $rvsstr;

  if ($strng === $rvsstr) {
    echo "Number is Palindrome";
  } else {
    echo "Number is not palindrome";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as this?

```
function isPalindrome(string $word) : bool
{
  $word = strtolower($word);
  if(strrev($word) === $word){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}   

echo isPalindrome('Deleveled');
```

Answer (score 0):

People are already correct here, anyway simply you can try this.

```
function checkPalindrome($string) {
  $string = strtolower($string);
  return $string == strrev($string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**So, first of all, what is palindrome?**

Palindrome is a word, phrase, or sequence that reads the same backward as forward.

So, to know wether the string is a palindrome or not, we only need to reverse the original string and then compare it.

Let's say we want to check wether the string `Level` is a palindrome or not:

```
$str = 'Level';
```

This step is for ignoring the case-sensitivity so `Level` and `level` will be considered the same.

```
$str = strtolower($str);
```

Then we can use the [strrev()](https://php.net/strrev) to reverse the string, then compare it to the original as follow:

```
echo (strrev($str) === $str) ? 'Palindrome' : 'Not palindrome';
```

You can also write it with if-else block if you consider it easier to read:

```
if (strrev($str) === $str) {
    echo "Palindrome";
} else {
    echo "Not palindrome";
}
```

Final code:

```
$str = 'Level';
$str = strtolower($str);
echo (strrev($str) === $str) ? 'Palindrome' : 'Not palindrome';
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Explaination added. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function isPalindrome($string): bool {
    return strtolower($string) === strtolower(strrev($string));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find solution for my 'kąyąk' problem when You have different characters encoding.

Below is originally from php.net comment changed sligtly by me to see on xdebug in phpStorm whats going on.

```
public function isPalindrome(): bool {
    $r = '';
    for ($i = mb_strlen($this->string); $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $r .= mb_substr($this->string, $i, 1);
    }

    for ($i = 0 ; $i <= strlen($r); $i++) {
        $o = mb_substr($this->string, $i, 1);   // original current char
        $s = mb_substr($r, $i, 1);              // inverted current char   

        if ($o != $s) {
            return false;                              // if does not match return false
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = readline("Enter word: ");
$i=0;
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($a) && substr($a,$i,1) == substr($a,strlen($a)-($i+1),1); $i++);
echo ($i == strlen($a))?"Pallindrome":"Not Pallindrome";
```

> $i < strlen($a) && substr($a,$i,1) == substr($a,strlen($a)-($i+1),1)

This test is the key where the loop tries to keep checking if the characters starting from the left of the string matches with the characters from the right, and it should continue till all characters are checked or till it doesn't find a matching character.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.